# How do you convert audio progress bar code so that it has a gradient in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, audio

As I did, the gradient itself was just displaying just how I started to decrease it, it just flattened and did not work as I wanted, and I wanted to gradually increase the progress of the bar, this rainbow gradient and not the frog was completely and flattened in addition. Thank you in advance for the help

Progress Bar Screenshot: [image]

HTML

```
<div class="video-progress hide" style="height: 3px;">
   <canvas class="progressbar-value" style="width: 0%;"></canvas>
   <div class="progressbar-load" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript with (JQuery 3.4.0)

```
var music = $('#music')[0];
var audio = $('#music');
var playButton = $('.button-play');
var pauseButton = $('.button-play play');
var timer = $('.time-container');
var progressBar = $('.progressbar-value');
var progressContent = $('.video-progress');
var nowPlaying =  $('.description');
var visualizer = $('.visualizer');
var overlay = $('.content-overlay');
audio.bind('timeupdate', function(){
  var track_length = music.duration;
  var secs = music.currentTime;
  var progress = (secs/track_length) * 100;
  var tcMins = parseInt(secs/60);
  var tcSecs = parseInt(secs - (tcMins * 60));
  var canvas = $('.progressbar-value');  
  if(canvas.getContext){  
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');         
    var rainbow = ctx.createLinearGradient(10, 0, 2000, 0);
    rainbow.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(26,  188, 156, .9)'); //blue
    rainbow.addColorStop(1/5, 'rgba(52,  152, 219, .9)'); //green
    rainbow.addColorStop(2/5, 'rgba(241, 196, 15,  .9)'); //yellow
    rainbow.addColorStop(3/5, 'rgba(230, 126, 34,  .9)'); //orange
    rainbow.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(211, 84,  0,   .9'); //red
    ctx.fillStyle = rainbow;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 2000, 75);
  }
  progressBar.css({'width' : progress + ".'"%"'."});
  if(tcSecs < 10){tcSecs = '0' + tcSecs;}
  timer.html(tcMins + ':' + tcSecs);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not a complete example and is not clear what kind of animation you want on your progress bar, but the rectangle you are drawing with `fillRect` has a fixed size:

> `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 2000, 75);`

With that the rectangle width is always 2000 there won't be any progress animation...

Let's start with a simple snippet that animates a progress bar.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var rainbow = ctx.createLinearGradient(10, 0, canvas.width, 0);
rainbow.addColorStop(0,     'rgba(26,  188, 156, .9)'); //blue
rainbow.addColorStop(1 / 5, 'rgba(52,  152, 219, .9)'); //green
rainbow.addColorStop(2 / 5, 'rgba(241, 196, 15,  .9)'); //yellow
rainbow.addColorStop(3 / 5, 'rgba(230, 126, 34,  .9)'); //orange
rainbow.addColorStop(4 / 5, 'rgba(211,  84,  0,  .9)'); //redish
rainbow.addColorStop(1,     'rgba(250,   0,  0,  .9)'); //red


var size = 50

function animate() {
  if (size < canvas.width) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = rainbow;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 10, size++, 25);
  }
}

setInterval(animate, 20);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=600></canvas>
```

On this example the rainbow gradient is static and I increase the size of the rectangle.

Comment: And how to change now that this interval is the progress of music?

Comment: I'm doing it in css gradient and js just reduces the div covering this gradient but I do not know if it's a good idea

Comment: To change the interval to the progress of music, you will have to experiment with your `audio.bind('timeupdate',` _ _ _ _ looks like you are already calculating something that can be used: `var progress = (secs/track_length) * 100;` _ _ _ _ And no I don't think the mix of canvas and css is a good idea

Comment: I do not have any canvas for this gradient, I only use div and css + jquery, which decreases its width, how does the music go and what the progress bar reveals